# TypeORM Typescript: How to ignore case when comparing UUID?

Tags: javascript, typescript, orm, typeorm

This code bellow:

```
.findOne({ id: model.userId })!;
```

does case sensitive comparing. I want to compare `UUID` with `case insensitive`.

How can I do this?

I am using `MSSQL` as the database. It stores `GUID` in lowercase. But there is a problem, `TypeORM` always returns `Uppercased UUID`.

For example:

```
let application = await applicationRepo.findOne({id: model.id, ownerId: res.locals.owner.id});
```

Returns this:

```
{
    "id": "AFB3015E-BE49-EC11-AE4D-74D83E04F9D3",
    "name": ".....",
    "dateCreated": "1637384252132",
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "ownerId": "96BBB111-BE49-EC11-AE4D-74D83E04F9D3"
}
```

If possible I want to set and get uuid in lowercase.

How can I do this?

---

### Note

This is the entity example:

```
@Entity()
export class Application {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
    id: string;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @Column("bigint")
    dateCreated: number;

    @Column()
    status: string;

    @ManyToOne(type => Owner, owner => owner.applications)
    @JoinColumn({ name: "ownerId" })
    owner: Owner;

    @Column()
    ownerId: string;

    @OneToMany(type => User, user => user.application)
    users: User[];

    @OneToMany(type => ChatRoom, chatRoom => chatRoom.application)
    chatRooms: ChatRoom[];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could modify it locally by using [`toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase?retiredLocale=nl)

```js
const data = {
    "id": "AFB3015E-BE49-EC11-AE4D-74D83E04F9D3",
    "name": ".....",
    "dateCreated": "1637384252132",
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "ownerId": "96BBB111-BE49-EC11-AE4D-74D83E04F9D3"
}

const result = { ...data, id: data.id.toLowerCase() };

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it automatically? Any setting to do this?

Comment: @AlvinStefanus are you sure the uuids are stored lowercase in your sql db?

Comment: @AlvinStefanus any updates on this?